# Diferencia entre usar android:colorPrimary y colorPrimary en el theme de XML - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo una duda, en muchos cursos veo que para ciertos casos anteponen "android:" en los name="" del archivo .xml de theme en el directorio res, cuál es la diferencia entre ponerlos o no hacerlo?.